# Get assembly file version from an archive without unpacking

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, archive

I use the following code to get a C# assembly file version for files stored on a harddrive.

```
var vInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("assemblyPath").FileVersion;
```

How could I get an assembly file version for a file stored in an archive without unpacking it? Imagine, you don't have a permission to write to a harddrive. You would probably use some in-memory library for opening the archive and checking what you need to know.

Comment: SharpZipLib can unzip to a `MemoryStream`, but `GetVersionInfo()` seems to only accept a file name...

Comment: if you read a stream you dont need to write it to filesystem. use reflection to load it

Comment: I'm using DotNetZip which can unzip to a `MemoryStream` as well and I discovered that GetVersionInfo only accepts local path and that's the reason why I am asking.
@giammin Can you show me, how to use reflection to a stream?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek sorry but you can get only the version not the fileversion

Comment: @giammin At least something ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry but you can't without having a phisical file.

The only way to read the FileVersion is to use [FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo.aspx) which accept only a path.

And if you use reflector to see how it read the fileversion then you will see some unsafe native internal methods you cannot use...

```
private static string GetFileVersionString(IntPtr memPtr, string name)
{
    int num;
    string str = "";
    IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (UnsafeNativeMethods.VerQueryValue(new HandleRef(null, memPtr), name, ref zero, out num) && (zero != IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        str = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(zero);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Maybe you could get it with some [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). But this is not in my knowledge.

If you settle for `AssemblyVersion` you can use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) library:

```
Assembly assembly;
using (var data = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(LocalCatalogZip))
    {
        zip["assembly.dll"].Extract(data);
    }
    data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(data.ToArray());
}
var version = assembly.GetName().Version;
```

----------------UPDATE-----------------

Last thought: maybe you have permission to write a file in the temp folder: [Path.GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx)

Comment: Give me a code please, so that I can verify that you are not making it up :)

Comment: It is possible to read version information without going to a file, but you would need to read the PE file information directly to locate the resource section and then parse the RT_VERSION version.

Comment: @William I don't really understand you.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek William suggested to read the dll file (or stream, whatever) in binary mode and find the exact location of the version information. Set your Version to `1.23.456.7890`, compile and search your dll for this string. The PE format is well documented http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` actually loads the assembly into your application domain, and once loaded, it stays there. If you try to get the version from the same assembly second time, you get error (at least, I did).

Comment: @C-F because this operation costs you can cache the assembly versions instead of reading it every time.

Comment: @giammin, Chaching is not always possible. Imagine, I get a binary blob from time to time, which is supposed to be an assembly, and the task is to determine whether the vesion has changed from the previous time. I have no a-priori knowledge about what I have got and I need to determine the file version. In my solution I just ended up with creating a temporary file and getting its version using `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo`. Not optimal, not hard-drive-free, but worked for me.

Comment: And also, note that the "File Version" (got by `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo`) and the "Assembly version" (got by `Assembly.GetName().Version`) can be different!

Comment: @C-F I know the best solution is to use a temp file but the question was about not having it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nuget package Mono.Cecil

```
ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(stream)
```

You'll get a ModuleDefinition, containing all desired assembly info.